# How would you pass a filtered data frame in to a left_join in a shiny app?

Tags: r, join, shiny

I have tried outside the app and it works, but can't seem to do it inside the app.

Selections of the example code from the app (the relevant bits):

```
   # Input: Selector for choosing the indicator
   selectInput(inputId = "indicator",
               label = "Choose an indicator:",
               choices = as.vector(Indicators)),
```

...

```
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  #selected data
  selectedData <- reactive({
    data %>% 
      filter(Indicator == input$indicator)
  })

  #map data
  mapData <- reactive({
    left_join(poly, selectedData)
  mapData
  })
```

The `mapdata` is a shapefile but that shouldn't be an issue as it works outside the app.

I am wondering if there is anything else that I should be doing.

I guess this would be equivalent to some reproducible data:

```
Indicator <- iris %>% distinct(Species)
selectedData <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mean = mean(Sepal.Length))
```

I am hoping to pass this in to a ggplot.  It shows this error in the console:

> Error in ggplot: object 'mapdata' not found

as well as this in the app:

> Error: object 'mapdata' not found

In the debugger `options(shiny.error = browser)` I got this:

```
    function (e) 
{
  if (inherits(e, "shiny.silent.error")) 
    return()
  handle <- getOption("shiny.error")
  if (is.function(handle)) 
    handle()
}
```

Comment: You may need `left_join(poly, selectedData())`

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work for me. I have added some more info. It is the same error message as before.

Comment: In your code, you are returning `mapData` which is the object you are naming i.e. the third line  `mapData <- reactive({
    left_join(poly, selectedData()) })`

Comment: So how would I fix that?

Comment: Thanks. It still didn't work for me. I have added some additional information, but it doesn't recognise the mapdata table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  #selected data
  selectedData <- reactive({
    data %>% 
      filter(Indicator == input$indicator)
  })

  #map data
  mapData <- reactive({
    left_join(poly, selectedData())
  })
  output$ggplot_id <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = mapData()) +
        ...  #further definitions for your plot
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It isn't working for me. I might need to play around a bit more.

Comment: Actually it did work. I had mapdata instead of mapData.